# Javascript - setTimeout undefined?

Tags: javascript, timer, undefined, settimeout

For a reason that I cannot fathom, the following function doesn't seem to work.

```
function timerTick()
{
    var t=setTimeout(timerTick,1000);
}
```

Everything should be working, but when I call the function, the console simply says 'undefined'.

Ideas?

Comment: Why are you assigning the value to a `var` that never gets referenced again?  Do you mean to *return* the result of `setTimeout` instead?

Comment: The console output must come from somewhere else, the function is perfectly valid.

Comment: Add `alert('i am called');` inside timerTick(). If you are calling it from the console then 'undefined' is correct behaviour, since the function call produces no return object.

Comment: [`setTimeout` returns a timeout ID, which can be used to clear the timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout). Are you trying to find out how many milliseconds the `setTimeout` has left?

Comment: I'm trying to make an recursively looping function. I added the alert - it pops up once, then the console says 'undefined' and it never shows again.

Comment: This might help http://vimeo.com/12529436 Paul Irish : 10 Things I Learned from the jQuery Source. Fast forward to 07:40 and last about 5mins. Intead of using setInterval you can use setTimeout and call itself.

Answer (score 5):

Everything IS working. What you're seeing is the return value of the invokation of `timerTick` itself which, as it stands, does not have a return statement and whose return value will thus be `undefined`. (The local variable `t` is *not* returned automatically!)

If you add a

```
console.log( "It's me. Again!" );
```

*inside* `timerTick` and call it you'll be seeing it every second in the console as expected.

EDIT: Typo in code and clarification:  The return value of functions *not invoked from the console*, such as  through `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, will not be printed to the console.

Comment: Nope, still no go. It prints 'It's me. Again!' once, then says undefined and ends.

Comment: @help me: That might be weird. If you edit your question and paste the whole script block (or however you're actually using it) perhaps we'll be able to help out.

Comment: No it's not weird. Your answer is *almost* perfect. `undefined` printed in the console when you call `timerTick` is indeed simply the result of the function. The only mistake you made is that you confused `setTimeout`, which is expected to run just once, with `setInterval`, which does repeat until cleared.

Answer (score 0):

> Everything should be working, but when I call the function, the
>   console simply says 'undefined'.
>
> Ideas?

May be your past this code into console and press enter (for example, in Chrome)?
In this case console says 'undefined'.
If your need to run function timerTick try next:
1)

```
function timerTick()
{
    console.info('i am called');
    var t=setTimeout(timerTick,1000);
}
timerTick();
```

or
2)

```
(function timerTick()
{
    console.info('i am called');
    var t=setTimeout(timerTick,1000);
})();
```